# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass error for index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a seed which I made sure worked by testing it in the rails console beforehand. Now I am trying show the instance variable @services in my view, but I have an error that says it's nill.

Any ideas?

Thank you

```
//home.html.erb

  <div>
    <% @services.each do |service| %>
    <%= service.name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

```
//services_controller.rb
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_service, only: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @services = Service.all
  end

  def show
    set_service
  end

    private

  def set_service
    @service = Service.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

```
//service.rb

class Service < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
    has_many :reviews
end
```

This is the error that's being rendered

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: your `home.html.erb` is not connected to services controller it seems.

Comment: make sure you have `root 'services#index'` in your `config/routes.rb` file. And then put that html into `views/services/index.html`.
Then when you go to yourwebsite.com - everything should work just fine

Comment: Thank you I think it worked, but now it jumped to a different problem. "Couldn't find Service without an ID" 
Extracted Source
 `def set_service
    @service = Service.find(params[:id])
  end
end`

Comment: change `before_action :set_service, only: [:index, :show]` to `before_action :set_service, only: :show`. You don't need to do `set_service` for your index action I presume.

Comment: good point. Thanks again! Everything works fine now

Comment: You could also add this line `@services = Service.all` to your `home` method in whatever controller it is in, then you will have that variable populated with all the services as well.  I assume the page `home` is supposed to be the root?

Comment: Yes. I think that's what I should have done first. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add root URL mapping, and point it to services index action, as in  `root 'services#index'` in `config/routes.rb`
2. move content of `home.html.erb` to `views/services/index.html.erb`
3. change `before_action :set_service, only: [:index, :show]` to `before_action :set_service, only: :show`

See the comments on question :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
before_action :set_service, only: [:index, :show]
```

To this:

```
before_action :set_service, only: [:show]
```